# Error when inherit from form that uses dllimport-ed function

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, dllimport

I have created a C dll and I have been using it in C# Windows Forms applications over the last 2 months. I didn't have any problems with it until I needed to inherit from a Form that uses P/invoked functions.

The functions in dll:

```
    extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall setBrightness(long a)
    {
    ...
    }
```

P/Invoke the function in C#:

```
    [DllImport("UserDLL.dll")]
    public extern static void setBrightness(Int32 Brightness);
```

How I inherit from Form1 that uses p/invoked functions:

```
    partial class UserSide: Form1
    {
    ...
    }
```

The code compiles without any errors/warnings and the program seems to be executed without defects. But when I try to open the design of the UserSide Form the following screen appears:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? It might be useful to know that similar error appears when I load an image directly from file in Form1:

```
    StatusIcons[0] = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("ImgIcn/camera_test.png");
```

[image]

In order to solve this I moved the image in the resources, but I don't think it is wise to do the same with a dll (if it is possible to be done).
I am using VS2010.

Thank you in advance!

Chris..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the StackTrace in your screenshot the reason for the problem is that the designer runs code that should only execute at runtime when trying to display the form. Therefore, I suggest to move the critical code parts in `if` blocks that check the [`DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property, e.g.:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (!DesignMode)
    {
        // execute code that can only run at runtime
    }
}
```